# Android action bar showing icons in both light and dark themes

Tags: android, android-actionbar, icons

I want to show an action bar with icons in both light and dark themes. So I'm wondering whether I need to duplicate all the icon files?

I also wonder why the official icons are either opaque white or black, but the guidelines say its alpha should be 80% and 60% for each theme respectively.  Should I change every png?

In other words, is there any simple way to use an action bar with icons that work in both themes?

Comment: I can't even understand, why android does not support SVG, which is a few years available. So it would be possible, to fix up every icon to every theme and size. Instead of it, they created a mipmap instead of drawable folder for complete confusion.